# ASP.NET MVC 3 WITH RAZOR : How to pass selected checkbox' ids in a Partial view to controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, data-sharing

I have a partialview [_SearchProduct] within the main view, let's say [product] view. The Partialview  has **a number of checkboxes segregated into different sections** like search by company,search by product etc. with one [search] button.

A User can select multiple checkboxes. When user clicks [search] button **I need to pass ids of all selected checkbox to controller action** and re-render the page again considering the user's selection . Please guide me how to pass selected checkbox ids to my controller action.

My partial view is something like below:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>By Company</legend>
<table  style="border-style: none;">
   <tr>
        @{
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model.CompanyName)
            {

                i = i + 1;
            <td style="border-style: none;text-decoration:none;" >
                @Html.CheckBox("chkCompany",new {id="chkCompany_" + Model.CompanyId.Tostring()}) @Model.CompanyName
            </td>
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                    i = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>By Product</legend>
<table  style="border-style: none;">
    <tr>
        @{
             i = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model.Product)
            {
                i = i + 1;
            <td style="border-style: none;text-decoration:none;" >
                @Html.CheckBox("chkProduct",new {id="chkProduct_" + Model.CompanyId.Tostring()}) @Model.ProductName
            </td>
                if (i == 10)
                {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                    i = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

- checkboxes are dynamic
- Checkbox id represent the primarykey of respective table based on which i do filtering.

Please guide me>>

Comment: Is the number of checkboxes dynamic (will there always be the same checkboxes, or will it be a list of checkboxes of an unknown size?) Is there a reason you need the ids, or would boolean values of which checkboxes were checked suffice? Please provide the code you have now.

Comment: Added codes. At end of the partial view it has one [[search] button. Codes are not working just what it may look like.

Comment: are you open to try ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you have a structure containing names (of companies/products), and ids.

I would create a View Model structure that looked like

```
public class PartialViewModel //Make sure this is included in your main view model
{
    public List<ObjectsToInclude> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectsToInclude> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectsToInclude //Give this a better name
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Include { get; set; }
}
```

Then in order to bind them you could do

```
for (int i =0; i<Model.Companies.Count(); i++)
{
   <td style="border-style: none;text-decoration:none;" >
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Companies[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Companies[i].Include) @Model.Companies[i].Name
   </td>
   if (i == 5)
   {
       @:</tr><tr>
       i = 0;
   }

}
```

Then provided your post takes a parameter of `PartialViewModel` (or some `MainViewModel` where that contains an instance of `PartialViewModel`), you'll have lists of companies and products binded. You can loop through the list, and take the respective ids of anything checked to be included.

**Edit:** If you wanted a single comma separated array to be posted, it would be possible by by creating an onclick event for your checkboxes, and then setting a value of a hidden input every time a checkbox is clicked. But then your code would only work with JavaScript enabled. If you need a comma separated string, you can create it server side with the view model I suggested.

```
string companyIds = String.Join(",", model.Companies
    .Where(company => company.Include)
    .Select(company => company.Id));
```

Comment: We can simply add only one hidden field and on click of each checkbox we can append id of company which are checked by user and set that value in hidden field.

Comment: Could you tell me why? That sounds like an arbitrary restraint.

Comment: Whenever it's comma separated, it will be great at LINQ or SQL when we want to do any operation with it.

Comment: The methodology I gave you makes it easy to get an IEnumerable of Ids, which is already LINQ ready. Edited my answer to show you how you could turn this linq string into a comma seperated string.

Comment: I want to know one thing. What will i get in action method on my post method?

Comment: You mean what parameter will post take? It should take your view model, which will automatically bind.

Answer (score 0):

http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.in/2012/09/multiple-checkboxes-in-mvc-3-and-post.html